# How to recover Facebook account

Tags: facebook, account-recovery, facebook-account

Someone changed my Facebook account email and password 5 month ago. How can I recover my Facebook account?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.facebook.com/hacked

Go to above link and enter your username/email id and password which you used to login your account and follow the screen instructions.